# Searchable JS/Next.js site text extraction

Tags: webpack, full-text-search, babeljs, lunrjs

I have a Next.js documentation site at https://logary.tech [source](https://github.com/logary/logary/tree/master/docs), and would like to implement the document search, e.g. with [Lunr](https://lunrjs.com/guides/getting_started.html).

How do I program babel/webpack/nextjs to also extract text (perhaps as a pre-compilation step/babel plugin), into a json file, that I can use for input to Lunr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose to use hgtmlparser2 as part of the build pipeline against the dev server; this if found in the [buildIndex.js](https://github.com/logary/logary/commit/d824089e29c8d40624758431f4f58d3ae1433d97#diff-6ea0e5a5fecd64bff83143608e895c8b) file.

It outputs [pages.json](https://github.com/logary/logary/commit/d824089e29c8d40624758431f4f58d3ae1433d97#diff-5dc307625298aa15c145e634d44ec7e4) (in this commit you see the stub; browse forward in history for impl) — which is then compiled into the web app.

Then I use [LunR](https://github.com/logary/logary/commit/d824089e29c8d40624758431f4f58d3ae1433d97#diff-aa21f6830ba0600e36e196e76b1e668eR33) to perform the search.

From this commit: https://github.com/logary/logary/commit/d824089e29c8d40624758431f4f58d3ae1433d97